# How to display the date and time with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I kind of know how to display the time with PHP and MySQL but I need a little help.

I want to display the time something like this in the example below.

```
August 5, 2010 @ 8:47:28 PM
```

Here is the code I have so far that is listed below.

```
date('F j, Y', strtotime($date_created))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the chart at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to see which characters you need for hour/minute/seconds and AM/PM? For the @ you just hardcode it in.

```
date('F j, Y @ g:i:s A', $whatever);
```

Comment: Were you the one that came up with `date('F j, Y')` or did you just paste it from somewhere? All you need to do is look at that chart and modify the string to have the right characters which represent their respective time/date information much like I have it.

Comment: I came up with the code but its a little late and I'm kind had one too many beers? I'm suprised I can type. thanks for the quick answer thogh.

Comment: mii, dude. That's awesome. Do your hands get numb when you drink or something or are you just trying to hard to get your Blood Alcohol Content to .1337 and ending up in the Windows ME range.

(That's an xkcd reference, by the way.)